# How to space apart bootstrap label components?

Tags: css, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angular.js and serving bootstrap for my front-end.  I'm laying out labels with the following code:

```
<div class="some_labels">
  <label>
    {{main.text}}
    <span class="label label-default" ng-repeat="label in main.labels">
      {{label}}
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

The result looks like the following:

[image: labels]

How do I space the labels a few pixels apart from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set styling for the span element.

```
 <!-- Inline styling --> 
 <label>
    {{main.text}}
    <span style="margin-right: 5px;" class="label label-default" ng-repeat="label in main.labels">
      {{label}}
    </span>
  </label>
```

Put styling in its own stylesheet.

```
label span { margin-right: 5px; }
```